# Open a list of .asc files and create a brick or stack

Tags: r, raster

I'd like to create a brick raster from a large number of .asc files based on their names. I have tried a few ways (see below),  but was unsuccessful:

```
setwd("C:/")
b <- brick(list.files(pattern = glob2rx("total_aground_live_biomass_2000_*_*.asc")))
b <- brick(system.file(pattern = glob2rx("total_aground_live_biomass_2000_*_*.asc"), package = "Raster"))
```

Could someone help me? I also wonder how to use glob2rx to only read files with the following pattern:total_aground_live_biomass_***[only years 1995, 2000, 2005]***__*.asc. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you have `.asc` files for different years, which you want to stack together by year.

Assuming the files are in the same directory (let's call it `datadir` for simplicity) and have a consistent naming convention, this is how I would do it:

```
library(raster)

#vector of years
yr <- c('1995','2000','2005')

# file name pattern
patt <- 'total_aground_live_biomass_(*.).asc$' 

#list files, optionally without recursive
fls <- list.files(datadir,patt,full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)

#stack files per year
stcks <- lapply(yr,function(x) stack(grep(x,fls,value=TRUE)))
```

This should hive you a nice list of three raster stacks, one for each year as defined in `yr`. You need to use `stack` to stack files from disk together. If you still need them to be raster bricks after that, you can just covert them with `brick`.

Comment: Thanks! If I want to create a list of files with both names types `glob2rx("AG_2000_*_1.asc")` and  `glob2rx("AG_2000_*_2.asc")` (e.g. AG_2000_02_2.asc, AG_2000_11_1.asc), how to proceed? My guess was to write
`glob2rx("AG_2000_*_[1-2]{1}.asc")` but it does not work

Comment: I would directly use a regular expression. In this case, `"AG_2000_\\d{2}_(1|2).asc$"` should do the trick. `\\d{2}` references two digits, and `(1|2)` is a simple 1 or 2 operation. The brackets limit the or operation to a subgroup of the string